# How to get process location using Python 2.7?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, process

I am searching for a way to retrieve the location path (path of the corresponding exe-file) of a Windows Process using Python. I managed to get lots of information like PID, name etc. but no chance for the location.

Any suggestions that may help me are very appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by using the subprocess module in conjunction  with WMIC. For anyone who is interested, here is my final solution:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'wmic process where "name=\'notepad.exe\'" get ExecutablePath'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked out [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil)?

```
pip install psutil
```

or even better...

```
conda install psutil
```

It has a exe method which may do the trick

exe()[source]
The process executable as an absolute path. On some systems this may also be an empty string. The return value is cached after first call.

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.pids()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 46, 48, 50, 51, 178, 182, 222, 223, 224,
 268, 1215, 1216, 1220, 1221, 1243, 1244, 1301, 1601, 2237, 2355,
 2637, 2774, 3932, 4176, 4177, 4185, 4187, 4189, 4225, 4243, 4245,
 4263, 4282, 4306, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4337, 4339, 4357, 4358,
 4363, 4383, 4395, 4408, 4433, 4443, 4445, 4446, 5167, 5234, 5235,
 5252, 5318, 5424, 5644, 6987, 7054, 7055, 7071]
>>>
>>> p = psutil.Process(7055)
>>> p.name()
'python'
>>> p.exe()
'/usr/bin/python'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to install additional python modules.

Comment: This does not work for me if the process was started from a network share like //some-share/folder/proc.exe. The path returned by p.exe() is /some-share/folder/proc.exe, so it is missing a /.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report to fix network paths on Windows: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1934

Answer (score 3):

> get the file location by name or pid

this would do the job (python 3.6) :

```
from win32com.client import GetObject


def Process_path(processname):
    WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
    processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')                #get list of all process
            for p in processes :                                #for each process :
                if p.Properties_("Name").Value == Processname : #if the process name is the one we wanted
                    return p.Properties_[7].Value               #return the path and break the funcion
            return "no such process"                            #no such process (if the funcion didnt break till now return false)

print(Process_path("process.exe"))
```

and if you want to get the locaiton by pid try this :

```
from win32com.client import GetObject


def Process_path(pid):
    WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
    processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')                
            for p in processes :                                
                if p.Properties_("ProcessID").Value == pid: 
                    return p.Properties_[7].Value               
            return "no such process"                            

print(Process_path("1111"))
```

Comment: This was really helpful. `p.Properties_[7].Value` is they key

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a solution that gave me the path where the process is running currently not the source path like '/usr/bin/python', So you can try:

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process(your pid)
path = p.cwd()
print(path) #/var/www/html/app_name
```